# htaccess RewriteRule in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to do a custom rewriterule in Wordpress.

I got a **page** http://example.org/blabla, and I want to redirect http://example.org/blabla/qwerty on the same page but with the "qwerty" in paramater.

Actually I got this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I'm trying to add just under the *RewriteBase /*

```
RewriteRule ^blabla/(.*)$ /index.php?post=1024&myparam=$1 [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't work. Can some one help me with this? post = 1024 is the post id of the page "blabla" in my wordpress administration panel.

Thanks.

Comment: This won't work in mod_rewrite rules. You will need to do it using WP rewrite APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I use the API like anubhava told me.

Comment: Ressource: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-add-a-page-template